# SQL SELECT GROUP BY and join the row with certain value

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

tbl_car

```
id_c | name car
1    | VW
2    | Audi
3    | Ferrari
```

tbl_auto_accessorize

```
id_a | id_c | fuel | gpl | abs
1    |  1   | 0    |  1  | 0   
2    |  1   | 1    |  0  | 1
3    |  2   | 0    |  1  | 1
4    |  2   | 1    |  0  | 1
5    |  3   | 0    |  1  | 0
```

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT id_a,id_c,abs
FROM tbl_car LEFT JOIN
     tbl_auto_accessorize
     ON tbl_accessorize.id_c = tbl_auto.id_c
GROUP BY id_c
```

the return in column abs is 0 because the first row is 0 but the same `id_c` have another row with 1.
I need a result equal to 1 because at least one is 1 of the same car.

Result:

```
id_c | abs
1    | 1
2    | 1
3    | 0
```

Comment: I don't consider your question to be complete, because there is no problem statement.  Can you describe what your query is supposed to be doing, or what you need here?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/1822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want `max()`:

```
SELECT c.id_c, MAX(aa.abs)
FROM tbl_car c LEFT JOIN
     tbl_auto_accessorize aa
     ON aa.id_c = c.id_c
GROUP BY c.id_c;
```

As a rule, all the columns in an aggregation query should either be in the `GROUP BY` or be the arguments to aggregation functions.  That is why I removed `id_a`.

Comment: With this sql i have only only row. i need all rows.

Comment: @Simsar78 . . . I don't understand.  This should return a separate row for each `id_c`.

Comment: @Simsar78 . . . This still seems to answer the question.